# Unable to import BACPAC from SQL Azure into SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, azure

I get the message below when attempting to import my database from SQL Azure. I believe this is following the upgrade to V12.

I have just installed SQL Server 2014 SP1 but it doesn't appear to have solved the issue. Current version of SQL Server Management Studio is:

12.0.4100.1

Any help most appreciated!!

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The Element or Annotation class SqlDatabaseOptions does not contain the Property class QueryStoreStaleQueryThreshold. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: You might have a look here as a place to start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341457/import-bacpac-fails-with-does-not-contain-querystorestalequerythreshold