# Restoring database from Azure BACPAC gives an error

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, bacpac

I'm trying to restore database created as the BACPAC on Azure.

1. I have exported the Azure database to Azure Storage
2. Downloaded the BACPAC file to local computer.
3. I have used build in functionality of SQL Server Management Studio, which is "Import Data-tier Application...".

But it gives me following error:

> *The Element or Annotation class SqlDatabaseOptions does not contain the Property class CatalogCollation.*

Full error info :

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

INFORMATION:

The Element or Annotation class SqlDatabaseOptions does not contain the Property class CatalogCollation. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)
```

I am restoring it on SQL Server 2014. I have tried to use both Sql Server Management Studio 2014 and 2017.

Any one can help?

**UPDATE:**
[This fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341457/import-bacpac-fails-with-does-not-contain-querystorestalequerythreshold) doesn't work for this case:

My error is regarding the **CatalogCollation** and not the **QueryStoreStaleQueryThreshold**...

Comment: @mitch This fix has not worked for me....

Comment: Are you using the latest SSMS version (17.7)?

Comment: @DanGuzman no I am using 17.3, do you think that might be it ?

Comment: It's always best to use the latest SSMS version with Azure SQL Database to keep up with incremental changes. I can't say for sure that you address your problem but it's easy to try (Tools--->Check for updates). Let me know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @DanGuzman yep you were right, after updating this to newest 17.7 it started working. You could answer this question and I would marked it, but someone marked this as a duplicate...

Comment: I re-opened you question and added the answer. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's always best to use the latest SSMS version with Azure SQL Database to keep up with incremental changes. The problem is that you were using the older version of SSMS (17.3).

You can get the latest SSMS version from the menu (Tools--->Check for updates).